Value of electronic hand-written signature
It becomes increasingly popular to sign documents on electronic displays, either with your finger or a special pen.
Say, someone (call him John) claims they signed a document at your shop, but this was not the document you presented later (in court, or to claim some payment). It would probably not that easy for you to prove otherwise, right?
I mean, it is easy to swap documents in a database, and even if you demonstrate the software in court, it is hard to prove that the software was exactly the same (and not tampered with) on the day that John signed and even if it was the same, to prove that does not have some secret button to show manipulated content to the customer John.
On the other hand, I never heard of above problem in practice, so I probably missed something.

For important documents, I believe it's normal to use electronic notary services. These services guarantee not to manipulate the content. And since they're not a party to the contract, they would have little reason to do so, so they're usually trusted.

I’ve voted to close this question as opinion‑based. Your question appears to be primarily a procedural one and as such depends on the argument the attorneys present. It is certainly possible the manipulated document is deemed legally binding, but it is also possible the electronic document is considered worthless.

This question can be answered using the chain of custody principle for evidence. It's not opinion-based and document signing software often have safeguards to guarantee the legality of the signature. I vote to remain open.

Are you interested in any specific domain of law (private law, criminal law, tax law, …)? Who are the involved parties (e. g. B2B, B2C, C2C, or state vs. citizen)? What kind of business is conducted (e. g. not a real estate sale → 311b Ⅰ 1 BGB)? In particular, has there been an agreement on form? What kind of parameters does the visual signature device record (timing, tilt, proximity or pressure, position of resting hand) at what resolution (e. g. 300 points per inch)? Do the involved parties show a prior history (e. g. there have been dozens of uncontested contracts of similar form)?

@KaiBurghardt What I had in mind where situations in which a customer signs some contract with a business (like buying a product, a phone contract, an insurance). It may be the first time that the customer signs a contract with that business. The signature is done with a special pen on a display, I do not know how the software works and what it actually records.

Yeah, OK. And do we contest just the (possible) manipulation, or do we contest the entire contract was void? Do the parties still agree there is a (as in some) valid contract, but only disagree about its contents (which is an issue independent from the signature)? Are there any clues the parties keep signed documents merely for the purposes of having a written record? Would they have agreed on doing the same legal transaction without creating/signing a digital document?

The question is about the extended possibility to manipulate the content of the contract (in contrast to a paper document). Image the company wants to collect payments from the customer, but the customer says: "True, I signed a contract, but it said 20€ per month, not 40€ per month. I refuse to pay." In this case, how does the company show (in a court of law) that the actual signed contract said "40€ per month"?
